# Call an http api endpoint using axios through an excel addin

Tags: https, office-js, excel-addins

I am calling an http endpoint using axios in an excel addin project. However I am unable to call the endpoint because the addin has an https certificate. It gets installed on every project I try to create using the addin cli. Is there a way to disable https so I can call this endpoint? Here is the error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=####'
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
'http://#######'. This request has been blocked;
the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: What happens if you use https in the URL of the endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

First, your question is missing an important detail that I was able to derive, but you should have included, your using NodeJS as your server.

This isn't technically a duplicate, but the question is really `How to disable SSL in NodeJS, Yeoman Office-JS Template` as it seems you have already figured out you can't call an `http` endpoint from an SSL enabled Office Add-In.

I'm not 100% how to disable SSL in NodeJS, but try changing the Dev URL to `http`. In `webpack.config.js` --> `const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";` --> `const urlDev = "http://localhost:3000/";`.

If you have access to the backend server and can get SSL configured, your better off setting up a `API Gateway/Proxy` such as `krakend` to proxy `http` requests.

I know I just had to disable SSL in my project for the same reason, but I use Visual Studio, so I can't test NodeJS.

See --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461455/5079799

Comment: I could not disable SSL by changing urlDev on the webpack config file. Managed to set up krakend with a self signed cert, but I now I get this error "xhr.js:210 GET https://localhost:8080/v1/info/#### net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" I am able to curl and get a response from the krakend endpoint but I cant call from the excel addin.

Comment: I do not have access to the backend server. I ran krakend locally using docker. I guess i'll try disabling https for the nodejs server. Thanks.

Comment: Did you import the cert into your local trusted store? When setting up KrakenD I used Insomnia to test the API for SSL Errors outside of office-js. But, for simplicity, you should be able to disable SSL on Node for testing. I know it was easy in Visual Studio which I much prefer over NodeJS for the solution explorer and JS console. See here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736058/5079799

Comment: I basically merged a VS 2022 template w/ a VS 2017 template. stripped the VS template all together and use the yo office files in VS. Each time I build via `npm run build` then start my project, but this allows `polyfill` which isn't part of the VS templates.

Comment: I've debated releasing a project scaffold on `git` but not 100% I can license wise?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to change an add-in created with [`yo office`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator), so its `devServer` to uses **http** instead of https, so any `fetch` to http end points won't result in ***mixed content***.

In **webpack.config.js**:

- The generated devServer.[server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverserver) has https definitions.  Replace or comment out the generated `server` value and use `"http"`.

  ```
  devServer: {
      server: "http",
  /*
      server: {
          type: "https",
          options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
  */
  },
  ```
- Replace all `https://localhost:3000` with `http://localhost:3000`.

In **manifest.xml**:

- Replace all `https://localhost:3000` with `http://localhost:3000`.

In **.vscode\launch.json**:

- Replace all `https://localhost:3000` with `http://localhost:3000`.